# JSON Assertion to check format of JSON in Jmeter

Tags: json, regex, testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Jmeter for the first time and have response data as follows:

```
{"types":[{"type":"tag","probability":"0.94"},{"type":"word","probability":"0.03"},{"type":"search","probability":"0.01"},{"type":"model","probability":"0.0"},{"type":"express","probability":"0.0"},{"type":"serial","probability":"0.0"}],"suggestions":[{"model":"AXT","dist":0.4286},{"model":"XL","dist":0.4},{"model":"03H","dist":0.4},{"model":"03","dist":0.4},{"model":"1435","dist":0.375}]}
```

I am trying to validate with regex if the JSON has specific format that to have type and probability under types and model and dist under suggestions.
I used following but it does not validate

```
$.types[*].type
```

Comment: What error are you getting? The json path expression you have returns `["tag", "word","search","model","express","serial"]`. Is this not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JSON Assertion is the good way to proceed, maybe it worth considering asking for a [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/) and validating the response using [JSR223 Assertion and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)?

If you don't have the schema you can generate it from your JSON using online tools like [this one](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter), it gives me something like:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "types": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "probability": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "type",
            "probability"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "probability": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "type",
            "probability"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "probability": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "type",
            "probability"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "probability": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "type",
            "probability"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "probability": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "type",
            "probability"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "type": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "probability": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "type",
            "probability"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "suggestions": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "model": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "dist": {
              "type": "number"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "model",
            "dist"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "model": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "dist": {
              "type": "number"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "model",
            "dist"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "model": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "dist": {
              "type": "number"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "model",
            "dist"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "model": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "dist": {
              "type": "number"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "model",
            "dist"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "model": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "dist": {
              "type": "number"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "model",
            "dist"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "types",
    "suggestions"
  ]
}
```

The above schema has been auto-generated from your JSON file, you might need to amend it according to your requirements.

So you can:

1. Save the schema to your hard drive next to the .jmx script
2. Add the following libraries to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

   - commons-digester-1.8.1.jar
   - commons-validator-1.6.jar
   - everit-json-schema-1.14.0.jar
   - handy-uri-templates-2.1.8.jar
   - joda-time-2.10.2.jar
   - json-20201115.jar
   - re2j-1.3.jar
3. Add JSR223 Assertion as a child of the request which returns the above response
4. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   def schema = org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.load(new org.json.JSONObject(new File('schema.json')))
   try {
       schema.validate(new org.json.JSONObject(prev.getResponseDataAsString()))
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
       AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(ex.getMessage())
   }
   ```
5. If the response will not match schema - the assertion will fail the sampler.

More information:

- [Introduction to JSON Schema in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-json-schema-in-java)
- [JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema)

Comment: when you say the libraries have to be added to the Jmeter classpath, are those libraries to be added under /lib/ext folder and then in user.properties file under bin folder we need to add /lib/ext file path to recognize those jars?

Comment: If I follow to add these jar files to user.properties then JSR223 Assertion Postprocessor under HttpRequest does not give error but if I change anything in JSON file it still does not give error